# SWTJar and external libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I've got a launchable .jar, insofar as it displays the shell.  However, when I press a button that has a listener that creates a new dialog that has this line:
`JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();`
it crashes `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException`

I've got json-simple-1.1.1.jar, but I don't know where to put it so the class loader gets it.

Works fine when launched from within the eclipse environment, so it's only when I'm in the jar-in-jar-loader world of SWTJar am I encountering this problem.

Comment: Did you check if it gets exported along with your jar? Did you try to put the json-simple-1.1.1.jar in the same folder as your executable?

Comment: it's in the jar created with SWTJar, and in the folder that the jar is in

Comment: Hmm, and it is in your build configuration as well? (build.properties in your project)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out:

in the `main()` method of the targetmainclass of the SWTJar build, before I call the constructor:

```
      URLClassLoader cl;
    try {
        cl = (URLClassLoader)SWTLoader.class.getClassLoader();
          Method addUrlMethod = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
          addUrlMethod.setAccessible(true);

          URL jsonsimpleUrl = new URL("rsrc:json-simple-1.1.1.jar");
          addUrlMethod.invoke(cl, jsonsimpleUrl);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | MalformedURLException | IllegalAccessException
            | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for jface; the classloader seems to be attempting to load it in org.swtjar.SWTLoader line 48 before my main class is loaded, or it's trying to do it too soon or something.

I have to actually extract the .class files from the .jars to make that work